# How long does it take to create an index in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I recently got the advice to create some indexes, here is my sql code

```
CREATE INDEX my_idx1 ON identdb (name,long1,lat1,date,count);
CREATE INDEX my_idx2 ON identdb (name,long1,lat1,date);
CREATE INDEX my_idx3 ON identdb (long1,lat1,date);
CREATE INDEX my_idx4 ON identdb (long1,lat1);
```

There are 7 million rows, 7 columns, and I am doing this on a local Database.

It has been running for about 16 hours. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you got some bad advice. The first and third indexes provides all the functionality given by the 2nd and 4th indexes you have created.

Comment: @invertedSpear ah, I see. You could delete your comment... as I have done to mine :-)

Answer (score 3):

It can take a while, although 16 hours seems excessive.  Do a `show processlist` and see if the `CREATE INDEX` is still running, or if it is blocked on something.

By the way, two of your indexes are redundant (`my_idx2` and `my_idx4`).  An index which is the prefix of another index is unnecessary, as the longer index can be used anywhere the shorter index would have been used.